# Angular 7. NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! Even when app.module has HttpClientModule. How to fix it?

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Angular 7, and I am trying to use a service that uses HttpClient to call an API link from my APIController in my .Net Core MVC application. Whenever I tried to test in the cmd window after typing in ng test, it gives me an error, and it's only for the service I'm trying to fix:

```
ProductService should be created
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

Here's how I wrote the code in the following files below:

*product.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from '../product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  productsUrl = "api/ProductsAPI";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<Product[]>('getProducts'))
      );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      //// TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      //this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

The product.service file has HttpClient in it, and I read that it doesn't work unless HttpClientModule is in the import section of app.module file, and the product.service class is in the providers section.

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ProductService } from './products/product.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It still gives me a 'No provider for HttpClientModule' error.  I want to use the product.service, and import it into another component.

Does anyone have any suggestions or answers on how to remedy this problem?

Comment: can you please copy paste the output of 'ng --version'  and share you're code of your spec file?  everything works find if you launch `ng serve` or `ng build`?

Comment: I have a same error like this when using import HttpClientModule in my module so I change to HttpClient and everything work fine. Can you try that

Answer (score 5):

I have a way to remove the nullInjetorError problem.  I thought that I have to put the HttpClientModule class in the import section of the app.module.ts file for the product.service file, but it turns out that I have to import it into the import section of the spec file, product.service.spec.ts.

*product.service.spec.ts*

```
describe('ProductService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ProductsComponent],
    imports: [HttpClientModule]
  })
  );
```

And when that problem still persists in the product.component, I added the HttpClientModule class into the import section of product.component.spec.ts file,m and it fixed the problem.

*product.component.spec.ts*

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductsComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

I didn't need to add the HttpClientModule class into the import section of app.module.ts, I just needed to add it to the import section of the spec files, and that resolved my problem with the 'NullInjectorError:  No provider for HttpClient.' problem.

I hope this can help for those who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have the error from `app.component.spec.ts`. You must also import the necessary components and modules for testing, try this:

---

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ your_component ],
  imports: [ your_module ],
  providers: [ your_service ]
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Okay, tried what you suggested.  I ran the ng test command, and I got more errors than one.  I removed, and it's caused by adding the 'AppModule' in the imports section.